# Python > passing variables of a string into a method

Tags: python, string, methods, replace, indices

I'm looking to replace a list of characters (including escaped characters) with another.

for example:

```
l=['\n','<br>','while:','<while>','for:','<for>']

s='line1\nline2'

s.replace(l[0],[l[1])
```

but passing the list indices through the method produces no effect.

I've also tried using

```
s=l[1].join(s.split(l[0]))
```

How can I replace a list of characters with another without expressing the pairs each time in the function?

Comment: sure it does, you just have to bind the result back to the variable `s = s.replace(l[0],l[1])`. having said that, your way of doing it is a *bad way*.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in the comments, the problem with your code is that you assumed that the `replace` works in-place. It does not, you have to assign the value it returns to the variable.

But, there is a better way of doing it that involves dictionaries. Take a look:

```
d = {'\n': '<br>', 'while:': '<while>', 'for:': '<for>'}

s = 'line1\nline2\nwhile: nothing and for: something\n\nnothing special'

for k, v in d.items():
  s = s.replace(k, v)
print(s)  # line1<br>line2<br><while> nothing and <for> something<br><br>nothing special
```

The advantage of using dictionaries in this case is that you make it very straightforward **what** you want to replace and what **with**. Playing with the indexes is not something you want to do if you can avoid it.

Finally, if you are wondering how to convert your list to a dict you can use the following:

```
d = {k: v for k, v in zip(l[::2], l[1::2])}
```

which does not break even if your list has an **odd number of elements.**

Answer (score 0):

```
l=['\n','<br>','while:','<while>','for:','<for>']

s='line1\nline2'

for i in range(0, len(l), 2):
    s = s.replace(l[i], l[i+1])
```

You simply have to iterate over the list containing your desired pairs, stepping over 2 values each time. And then assign the result of the replacement to the variable itself (`replace` doesn't do inline replacement because strings are inmutable in Python)

Comment: juggling with the indexes like that is not something I would encourage but if the OP wants to have his input in a single list then ok.

Comment: He may receive the list as output. And using `i` and `i+1` is something which can be very difficult to consider ... *juggling*

Comment: This can be debatable but in that case I would also check to make sure my list has an **even number** of elements because if it does not, this code [fails](https://repl.it/repls/NovelUnfoldedChinchilla).

Comment: Sorry for the unconventional example. The input will be sourced from undetermined lists, but the constant would be that the replaced and replacement characters will be passed into the method from a list indices. Thank you both for your suggestions.